# RegEx to match five letter word NOT containing 'b,j,m,n'

Tags: php

I have a regex to match words that do not contain these letters but is only working for lowercase letters, is there a better way to do this?
`"\b[ac-iklo-z]{5}\b"`

Comment: Add the case-insensitive option, like `#\b[ac-iklo-z]{5}\b#i`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/\b[^bjmn\W]{5}\b/i` to do a case insensitive match on five-letters words without bjmn in them.

Comment: That would match the sequence "aa-aa". I think yent's answer works better.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify that you want to match uppercase letters also, I'm not sure on the syntax, but "/b[ac-iklo-zAC-IKLO-Z]{5}/b"

Comment: Thanks, didn't know if this was the right way to do it either but it works :)

Comment: I would however use the case-insensitive option posted by yent